# Plotting SpatialDesign object

Tags: r, plot, r-sf

I am working with the package 'spsurvey' and stumbled upon some difficulties in plotting the results.
I want to plot the generated points in 'Equalsites' on the polygon 'UT_ecoregions'. However, it doesn't work as straightforwardly with simple `plot` function with `add= TRUE`argument.

Here's the code that I am working with:

```
# Loading the required package 1====
library(spsurvey)
library(tidyverse)
# package 1 \ends----

# Loading the data that come along with the package====
 data("UT_ecoregions")

# Aggregation of the ecoregion areas per type
temp <- with(UT_ecoregions, tapply(Area_ha, Level3_Nam, sum))

set.seed(114) # to ensure the reproducibility of the exact same results

# a. Generate a list that contains specs of the survey design called 'Equaldsgn'
Equaldsgn <- list(None=list(panel=c(PanelOne=50), seltype = "Equal")) # 50 denotes the number of sample for each panel; seltype defines the type of random selection for the design.

# b. Selecting the sample
Equalsites <- grts(design = Equaldsgn, #ADlearn structure, usage, etc.
                   DesignID= "EQUAL",
                   type.frame = "area",
                   src.frame = "sf.object",
                   sf.object = UT_ecoregions,
                   maxlev = 5,
                   shapefile = FALSE)
# Visualizing the results: **this is where the problem lies**
plot(st_geometry(UT_ecoregions))
plot(st_geometry(Equalsites), add= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you need to set `reset = FALSE` in your first `plot` call.

```
plot(st_geometry(UT_ecoregions), reset = FALSE)
plot(st_geometry(Equalsites), add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have just tried this but it didn't work for me. It returned an Error in UseMethod ("st_geometry"). I think it's related to the class of the 'Equlsites' variable.

Comment: I now see that `Equalsites` is a sp object, so you would need to convert to sf first. `plot(st_geometry(sf::st_as_sf(Equalsites)), add = TRUE)` should work.

Comment: We recently converted old C code in `spsurvey` to `sf` functions, however we left a few things like design objects as `sp` objects, so @TimSalabim is right in just converting to `sf`.  We will get rid of all underlying `sp` objects in upcoming release of `spsurvey`.

Comment: It works now. Thank you for the helpful responses! I really look forward to the upcoming release of spsurvey. Keep up the great work!

Answer (score 0):

so I did some messy workaround that goes like this:

```
resPoints <- Equalsites@coords
plot(st_geometry(UT_ecoregions))
points(resPoints)
```

It currently works for me, but any other suggestions are much appreciated!